# How to disable session maintenance when creating a user with Authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authlogic

When a user is created, Authlogic sets a persistence token which it uses for session maintenance. As part of this process, it does a query like:

`User Exists (517.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM 'users' WHERE 'users'.'persistence_token' = BINARY 'xyz123123' AND 'users'.'deleted_at' IS NULL LIMIT 1`

which as you can see is pretty expensive on our database. This code is evidenced here: https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/4f03d6520d8b13394023f5cbc9ba74ab1464b89d/lib/authlogic/session/session.rb
This is particularly problematic with our user sync function which creates thousands of users and thus this query is very very expensive.

How can we disable this behavior during this operation and set it later? I tried to use `user.save_without_session_maintenance` but that didn’t seem to work for me.

Comment: Look like `persistence_token` is an important part of the gem logic. You can try to write monkeypatch / rewrite the logic of `reset_persistence_token?` and change `validates_presence_of :persistence_token, if: !new_user?`. But that is a bad idea.

Comment: `save_without_session_maintenance` is the correct method. Hard to troubleshoot further without your code though.

Comment: @JaredBeck We got bit by this again unfortunately. `save_without_session_maintenance` doesn't prevent the uniqueness validation from getting run on the persistence_token. As such we still see high query times during the lookup on the binary of the persistence_token column.

Comment: Is there a reason for the uniqueness validation? Is it just a precaution? I see it uses SecureRandom.hex(64), right? I imagine this should avoid most if not all collisions as it is.

Comment: Try creating an index on the `perisistence_token` and/or `deleted_at` columns?